# C# Web API HTML5 Audio Tag Seekable

Tags: c#, html, api, audio, seek

Im playing around with the C# Web API and built a RESTfull API to access resources in my Database.

What i want to achieve is a HTML5 Audio Tag is playing a mp3 loaded from the database. As the src attribute i make a request, and on the server i respond with a `ByteArrayContent`

The MP3 is playing ... so far so good. Im displaying the controls of the audio tag, but i cant seek through the MP3.

My Questions:

- Do i serve the right response for Seeking?
- Do i need to make a ranged request?
- Do i need any javascript to seek, or is the audio tag all i need?
- Does someone has an example to achieve this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) for having a decent player.

Comment: Do you have the problem with seeking only with your server, or is it a general problem?

Comment: thank you for the response. Im try to achieve it without any extentions and just in chrome. If i serve a static file on my server, i can seek through the mp3. This is the reason why im not sure about the ByteArrayContent

Comment: Does your server send the size of your file? If not, seeking will not work. Also have a look at this question about the range header: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2798931/79485